# Addition of Columns with default value in oracle having billions of record

Tags: performance, oracle, oracle11g, ddl, alter-table

I need to add 3 columns having default value in a table with 1.70 billion records in Oracle 11g. What is the best option to do this with minimum time?

Comment: You've probably already resolved this, but were the new columns defined as `not null`?

Comment: yes, it got resolved.  No, it will allow null values also.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get a performance boost when adding column values. If you're only picking a subset of rows then you can try for optimization there.

If the columns truly have a `DEFAULT` value then the value will actually be put there by Oracle when you `INSERT` and either (a) don't name the column in the column list or (b) specify its value as `DEFAULT`:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable (
  Col1 NUMBER(5) DEFAULT 10 NOT NULL,
  Col2 NUMBER(5) DEFAULT 20 NOT NULL,
  Col3 NUMBER(5) DEFAULT 30 NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES (DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT);
INSERT INTO MyTable (Col2, Col3) VALUES (21, 31);
INSERT INTO MyTable (Col2, Col3) VALUES (22, DEFAULT);
INSERT INTO MyTable (Col1) VALUES (11);

SELECT * FROM MyTable;

 COL1  COL2  COL3
----- ----- -----
   10    20    30  <-- VALUES (DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT)
   10    21    31  <-- (Col2, Col3) VALUES (21, 31); Col1 defaults because not named
   10    22    30  <-- (Col2, Col3) VALUES (22, DEFAULT); Col1 defaults because not named
   11    20    30  <-- (Col1) VALUES (11); Col2 and Col3 default because not named
```

So there's no need to check for `NULL`, if that's what you're worried about:

```
SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3, Col1+Col2+Col3 AS TotCols
FROM MyTable;

      COL1       COL2       COL3    TOTCOLS
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
        10         20         30         60
        10         21         31         62
        10         22         30         62
        11         20         30         61
```

If your question is about how to optimize for a subset of rows, please add more information.

Comment: Basically, I need to add new columns with default value so that existing row will also get updated with default values in new Column.  
Here we can add default null column and then run the script to update the values of column and then modify the default value of column but it takes too much time since it has 170 crore records 
OR 
We can directly add columns with default value but that will also take too much time to update crores of records.

Comment: @user1017936, if you specify the DEFAULT when you add the column, you won't need to update all the rows.

Comment: 1 Crore = 10000000. Yes, I know, but it will also lock the table for that period and for such large number of records, downtime will be huge.  So, I was looking for some other alternative.